# 3 failed SQL Server Updates (KB3045313,KB3045305) plus SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 3

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to upgrade to Windows X and I believe that 2 failed SQL Server 2008 patches are preventing this from happening.

I see this
[image: this]

in Windows Update along with this failed History:

[image]

...which refers me to this URL for more info, but I didn't see anything helpful there

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3045305

This is the version of SQL Server 2008 R2 that I am running:

```
select @@version

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64)   Jun 28 2012
```

08:36:30   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

I tried downloading SQLServer2008-KB3045305-x64.exe from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48005

and SQLServer2008R2-KB3045313-x64.exe from

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48017

Then, I ensured that the "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server" was not compressed, and did not have the archive flag set on this folder or any or the subfolders or files. I also turned switched the folder from compressed to not compressed. I tried to turn off the read only flag on everything in the top level folder but the flag keeps coming back mixed.

I then turned off my virus scanner and then ran the first exe, then the second. The outcome was the same, it begins by extracting to a temp folder and then quits and removes the folder with everything in it.

[image]

I thought that maybe I should upgrade to SP3 firts, so I tried download it from here

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27594

But the same thing happened, the extract fails with no error message.

Although I tried installing these 3 patches several times in various order and got the same result each time, I see what appears to be a log file from one of the installation attempts. This is what led me to believe that I needed to un compress my SQL folder. The file was here:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\Summary.txt

Here is the content:

```
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2068578304
  Exit facility code:            1204
  Exit error code:               0
  Exit message:                  Attributes do not match. Present attributes (Directory, Compressed) , included attributes (0), excluded attributes (Compressed, Encrypted).
  Start time:                    2015-08-01 01:57:35
  End time:                      2015-08-01 01:58:55
  Requested action:              Uninstall

Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  BESI-CHAD
  Machine processor count:       8
  OS version:                    Windows Vista
  OS service pack:               Service Pack 1
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered 
  Sql Server 2008      SQLEXPRESS           MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS             Database Engine Services                 1033                 Express Edition      10.3.5500.0     No        
  Sql Server 2008      SQLEXPRESS           MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS             SQL Server Replication                   1033                 Express Edition      10.3.5500.0     No        
  Sql Server 2008                                                          Management Tools - Basic                 1033                 Enterprise Edition   10.52.4000.0    No        
  Sql Server 2008                                                          Management Tools - Complete              1033                 Enterprise Edition   10.52.4000.0    No        
  Sql Server 2008                                                          Client Tools Connectivity                1033                 Enterprise Edition   10.52.4000.0    No        
  Sql Server 2008                                                          Client Tools Backwards Compatibility     1033                 Enterprise Edition   10.52.4000.0    No        
  Sql Server 2008                                                          Client Tools SDK                         1033                 Enterprise Edition   10.52.4000.0    No        
  Sql Server 2008                                                          Integration Services                     1033                 Enterprise Edition   10.52.4000.0    No        

Package properties:
  Description:                   SQL Server Database Services 2008
  SQLProductFamilyCode:          {628F8F38-600E-493D-9946-F4178F20A8A9}
  ProductName:                   SQL2008
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       10
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation edition:          EXPRESS

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Uninstall
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20150801_015726\ConfigurationFile.ini
  FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE,REPLICATION,SNAC_SDK,OCS
  HELP:                          False
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              False
  INSTANCEID:                    <empty>
  INSTANCENAME:                  SQLEXPRESS
  QUIET:                         False
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   False
  X86:                           False

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20150801_015726\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity SDK
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Server Replication
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

  Feature:                       Microsoft Sync Framework
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

There are no scenario-specific rules.

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20150801_015726\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm

Exception summary:
The following is an exception stack listing the exceptions in outermost to innermost order
Inner exceptions are being indented

Exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.InputSettingValidationException
    Message: 
        Attributes do not match. Present attributes (Directory, Compressed) , included attributes (0), excluded attributes (Compressed, Encrypted).
    Data: 
      DisableWatson = true
    Stack: 
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.InputSettingService.LogAllValidationErrorsAndThrowFirstOne(ValidationState vs)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.ValidateFeatureSettingsAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Action.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.InvokeAction(WorkflowObject metabase, TextWriter statusStream)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.PendingActions.InvokeActions(WorkflowObject metaDb, TextWriter loggingStream)
    Inner exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.DirectoryAttributesMissmatch
        Message: 
                Attributes do not match. Present attributes (Directory, Compressed) , included attributes (0), excluded attributes (Compressed, Encrypted).
```

Of course, I already told you that uncompressing the folder did not help.

Up to this point I've been ignoring these patches but I am not getting the option to upgrade and redeem my reserved copy of Windows X. I've read that this may be due to not having the latest patches installed.

What can I do to get these patches installed? I'm tempted to uninstall SQL Server, but I am afraid of hosing it and my multiple copies of Visual Studio. I've had bad luck with uninstallations in the past, even when followed by re-installations  because the reinstall usually encounters issues due to a unclean leftover state.

Your suggestions would be appreciated!

**Update**

Not sure why the log file, created on 8/1/2015, shows that I have a Vista machine. I have Windows 7. The file was created 3 days ago when I began trying to manually install these patches. I've never had Vista on this box, it was always Windows 7.

[image]

**Updated**
The error message above was likely the original log before I uncompressed all of the the folders and turned off the ARCHIVE flag. Subsequent install attempts did not result in an updated log file, surprisingly.

After reading that SQL 2008 R2 was not supported on Windows 10, I decided to uninstall it. I did, and cleared off 18 GB on my tiny 80 GB SSD C drive.

Since I never got the expected message that Windows 10 had been downloaded and ready for install, I tried to download the Media creation tool from here

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Same thing. it starts to run, then leaves the Task Manager with no sign on an error.

Comment: It took me a long time to write the question. Can you tell me why you voted to close it?

Comment: I tried to post it there. it prevents new users from posting more than two links.

Comment: Did you check `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server` folder as well to see if the compress bit is not set ? Check [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a94fcca0-b9cc-4287-90fe-f3151ef997ab/sql-server-2008-r2-installation?forum=sqlgetstarted) and [kb/957453](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/957453)